# jaxb enum based on regular enum - unmarshall issues

Tags: java, enums, jaxb

I'm facing a problem, and i hope someone can help me out.
I have a model project, which contains a lot of pojos, and also some enums.

i have a generic map, which holds key and value, which can be of any type.
the map looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo implements Serializable
     Map<Object,Object> myMap
```

One of the values which the map can hold is an enum.
Since i want the jaxb to marshall/unmarshall it, I'm trying to create something like

```
@XmlEnum(value=org.yyy.models.enum.FooEnum)
public class MyEnum
```

The enum class is a simple enum:

```
public enum FooEnum{
    ONE,TWO,THREE
}
```

Since i don't want to duplicate the values of the enum using @XmlEnumValue I want to know how i can add that dependency. again, without the need to maintain two sets of values (one in the enum, and one in my jaxb enum).

In all the example i saw, its pretty simple, as usually the class holds a member of a certain type, in my case, since the map can hold any value, i cannot add any restriction on it.

My problem is with the jaxb unmarshall, it seems like it is not able to convert the value from my test to the enum value - it doesn't throw exception, the unmarshalled value is null

here is the example:

```
    <table>
    <entry>
        <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Name</key>
        <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Test</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Type</key>
        <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:type="myEnum">ONE</value>
    </entry>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have almost everything right, but your problem is the context may not know anything about how to handle the enum class you've defined.

I was able to construct a small set of classes to produce the output you want without any special enum annotations.

**EDIT**: So after further evaluating the question, specifically related to unmarshalling, I modified the test to try to unmarshal the XML pasted in your question description (wrapped with a `<Foo></Foo>` tag) and re-marshal the obtained object to System.out to verify everything worked.
I created a file called "MyXml.xml" with the following content (from above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Foo>
    <table>
        <entry>
            <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Name</key>
            <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Test</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Type</key>
            <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:type="myEnum">ONE</value>
        </entry>
    </table>
</Foo>
```

Then, using a Foo class annotated like so:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Foo() {}

    // wrap your map in a table tag
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "table")
    // the entry will be the tag used to enclose the key,value pairs
    @XmlElement(name="entry")
    Map<Object, Object> myMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    public Map<Object,Object> getMyMap() {
        return myMap;
    }
}
```

The simple enum class, no annotations needed:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ONE, TWO, THREE;
}
```

This test:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create your context, and make sure to tell it about your enum class
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{Foo.class,MyEnum.class});
        // create the unmarshaller
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        // try to unmarshal the XML into a Foo object
        Foo f = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("MyXml.xml"));

        // if it worked, try to write it back out to System.out and verify everything worked!
        if ( f != null) {
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            m.marshal(f, System.out);
        }        
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Foo>
    <table>
        <entry>
            <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Type</key>
            <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="myEnum">ONE</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Name</key>
            <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Test</value>
        </entry>
    </table>
</Foo>
```

As you can see, no additional Enum management needed, and the correct output was observed.
Hope this helps.